# Oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, oscillation

I'm trying to solve this problem for some hours now but without success, I thought I would ask for help here. I detailed my doubts in the image below :

Both Coupled inductors have couple coeficient k = 1 and are ideal (infinite quality factor)
and these are the information:

```
C_b = infinite, beta = 200, V_BE = 0.7V, V_C_sat = 0
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRGudt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first thing I need to know how C1 is related to resonance frequency f of the circuit.
It seems like I can choose a frequency and I automatically get a needed value for C1.

The second thing I need to know is what value for L2 should choose so that I get the maximum feedback rate at the resonance frequency f

I have a lot of doubts I don't know if the circuit constitutes a Colpitts or Hartley oscillator and if I can use the known formulas and then how I would apply it my circuit.

Comment: Where did the circuit come from and what else was contained in the article about it?

Comment: Depending on who you ask, this circuit is called an Armstrong Oscillator or Meissner Oscillator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_oscillator With this info, you can at least search a bit more.

Comment: Instead of building it yourself, there are modules that are stable and can do this for you over a very wide range of frequencies:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305303/oscillator-circuit-of-10khz-to100khz/305321#305321

Answer (score 1):

the L and C form an [LC tank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).
Frequency is given by:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you have any clue about how to calculate L2 so that we get the maximum feedback rate at the ressonance frequency fo ?

Comment: From your schematic it looks like L1 and L2 are from a dual winding inductor so they should be the same value.